# program not working outside debugger vfp

Tags: debugging, combobox, visual-foxpro

I have a problem when running my visual fox pro application: I have a combo box that looses the list-item-id value when i run the application without the debugger on.When the debugger is on, I don't face this problem anymore. How can this happen?

Thank you

Comment: bug in code seems likely.....

Comment: I have checked and rechecked the code. It doesn't seem to have a problem that I can see. The combobox listitemid doesn't seem to get lost anywhere. It is very strange that it works perfect with the debugger on...

Comment: "It is very strange that it works perfect with the debugger on" - actually, no it's not. It's a classic symptom of a bug in your code.

Comment: The items are still in combo, because when i walk through the items and select another one the lsititemid changes accodring to the selected value.

Answer (score 1):

There must be some code which removes Items from Combo. look for Lost focus or validate or other events of combo.